# Chrome ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I have created my own Root CA and signed SSL certificate with it then imported Root CA into Windows trusted Root CA list and imported SSL certificate  into my web application server. When trying to access according web page I get ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID:

1. Chrome shows in the address bar:

[image]

2. Chrome shows when inspecting certificate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Chrome shows when I inspect Root CA
   [image]
   [image]
4. Chrome shows when inspecting Trusted Certificate Authorities
   [image]
5. Information about SSL certificate:
   [image]
6. Information about Root CA:
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know why but Chrome would not pick even when Root CA would get installed  through Chrome's interface. Only restart of Chrome helped me

```
chrome://restart
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.